# password is correct but still show Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'fundsupg_bse2' in plesk using mysql

Tags: asp.net, plesk, dbconnection

> ```
> The password is correct but still shows Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user
> ```
>
> 'fundsupg_bse2' in Plesk using MySQL.
>
> ```
> **Use:  Asp.net , Web forms 
> panel : plesk
> configuration : web.config file**
>  below is my connection string to connect the MySQL database.
> ```

add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=fundsupg_bse2;User Id=fundsupg_bse2;Password=Wp!8u1p7;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Answer (score 0):

Try convert the character '!' of your password with this in your configuration -> \u0021 this code is the equivalent in HEX/UTF-32 for your character.

```
For Example: "Server=localhost;Database=fundsupg_bse2;User Id=fundsupg_bse2;Password=Wp\u00218u1p7;"
```